# Csr matrix (scikit-learn svm.SVC coef_ attribute)

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a sklearn.svm.SVC object and train it by some data. Now I need to get first N values of

```
v = TfidfVectorizer()
train_data = v.fit_transform(data)
clf2 = SVC(kernel='linear')
clf2.fit(train_data, train_target)
print clf.coef_
```

In order to get most valuable words in set, I need to get absolute values of clf2.coef_ sparse matrix. How can I get first N words by absolute values?